# Images in grid should get largest size as possible

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone app, I need to have a maximum of 4 pictures horizontal next to each other. The images have always same width/height. Of course the width and also the height of the grid depends on screen. In case there are just 2 pictures, they should scale up to fill the space available. In case there are 4 they have to scale down.

How can I do this on xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the images into a horizontal StackPanel inside a Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="http://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/0/0.png"/>
        <Image Source="http://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/0.png"/>
        <Image Source="http://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/0/1.png"/>
        <Image Source="http://tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/1.png"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```